# Increment file name while writing file in Python

Tags: python, django

My code works and increments filename but only for two first files, after that it creates new strings in existing second file. Please help me upgrade code to increment go further.

```
text = 'some text'
file_path = '/path/to/file'
filename = 'textfile'
i = 1
txtfile = self.file_path + filename + str(i) + '.txt'
if not os.path.exists(txtfile):
   text_file = open(txtfile, "a")
   text_file.write(self.text)
   text_file.close()

elif os.path.exists(txtfile) and i >= 1:
   i += 1
   text_file1 = open(self.file_path + filename + str(i) + '.txt', "a")   
   text_file1.write(self.text)
   text_file1.close()
```

Comment: Is this running in loop?

Comment: Yes,sure. It loops through text strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your example is part of a loop, your resetting `i` to `1` in every iteration. Put the `i=1` outside of this part.

And it will also start at `1` when you restart your program - sometimes not what you want.

Comment: Perhaps to avoid it I have to add additional checking for existed files in location...